# How to add certificate rule through command line or programmatically?

Tags: c#, certificate

I want to add a new certificate rule through command line in Additional Rules which is under Software Restriction Policies. If any one know how to achieve it please answer me. I have  searched a lot in net. But i could not found any clue for this.

The Additional Rules is present under secpol.msc\Software Security\Software Restriction Policies\Additional Rules

Comment: maybe secedit is what you need http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742472(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: http://roque-patrick.com/windows/final/bbl0150.html